# GCM Notification for Topics Message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have problem with my application. I want to make an application that use GoogleCloudMessaging. I want use topics feature to send message to all device.

I have been try send and receive normal message. I mean form 1 device to another device. And it is success.

So, I adding feature to send and receive topics message. Because I didn't need different action for normal message and topics message. I use same onReveiced() method on class GcmBroadcastReceiver (didn't used GcmListenerService like example from google documentation). This is the code:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
...
}
```

and this code of GcmIntentService class:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
public static final String TAG = "GcmIntentService";

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) { // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that
         * GCM will be extended in the future with new message types, just
         * ignore any message types you're not interested in, or that you
         * don't recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Received Message : "
                    + extras.getString("message"));
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);


}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
// a GCM message.
private void sendNotification(String msg) {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

I got this respon from server when send topics message

```
  Response : {"message_id":XXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
```

Based on https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging, it is response format for success message.

My question is why I didn't got notification and message from topics message (on other device) while my topics message success sended (based on the response).

Comment: Because u have set title to GCM Notification !!

Comment: @M.S.P hem.. I think it won't effect with the notification. That just title of notification there is no connection with the content of message that I have been send.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the topic from the android client? You need to subscribe to topic before you can receive messages sent to topic. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmPubSub

Comment: @ArthurThompson Yups I already do that, with this code on the other class
pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(context);
pubSub.subscribe(regid, "/topics/"+ topics_name, null);

Comment: Could you try using GcmListenerService instead of WakefulBroadcastReceiver?